# Sorting and indexing between 2 numpy arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am having the following numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
y2 = np.array([[0.2,0.1,0.8,0.4],[0.4,0.2,0.5,0.1],[0.4,0.2,0.5,0.1]])
y1 = np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1]])
```

What I am trying to do is to get the position of `y1` compared to `y2`. To be more clear: `y1` is the label data and `y2` is the predicted data and I want to see in which rank position an algorithm predicted compared with the real data.

I am doing the following:

```
counter = 0
indexes2 = []
indexes = np.where(y1)[1]
sorted_values = np.argsort(-y2)
for value in sorted_values:
    indexes2.append(np.where(value==indexes[counter])[0][0] + 1)
    counter += 1
b = np.array(indexes2)
```

The output is correct:

```
>>> b
>>> array([2, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

But, I am pretty sure that there is a more elegant way of doing and more optimized. Any hint?

Comment: You could possibly try writing the `for loop` as a python list omprehension

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vectorize the nested loop**

We could get rid of the loop by making use of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
b = (sorted_values == indexes[:,None]).argmax(1)+1
```

**Some Improvement**

For performance, we could optimize the computation of `indexes`, like so -

```
indexes = y1.argmax(1)
```

**Bigger Improvement**

Additionally, we could optimize on `sorted_values` computation by avoiding the negation of `y2`, by doing -

```
sorted_values2 = np.argsort(y2)
```

Then, compute `b` by using broadcasted comparsion as done earlier and subtract the `argmax` indices from the length of each row. This in effect does the descending ordering along each row as done in the posted question, where we had negation of `argsort`.

Thus, the final step would be -

```
b = y2.shape[1] - (sorted_values2 == indexes[:,None]).argmax(1)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and my apologies for the late reply. I was afk this weekend. As you mentioned the third solution gives the best time. `y1` is always having only one non zero value, however `where` and numpy.nonzero` functions are searching the whole array to find desired indexes.I am curious if there is a way to avoid `where` function or `numpy.nonzero` to find this unique index where `1` is found. I created a function with a loop that breaks everytime it finds the `1` but is way slower. Any insights?

Comment: @MpizosDimitris As suggested in the post, did you try `indexes = y1.argmax(1)`?

Comment: Your suggestions decreased around 15% the time. However most of the time is spent on `argsort` function, which I guess it cant be optimized..